# HDInsight Cluster 4.0 with existing Hive metasore. Error - FailedToSetupDatabaseErrorCode

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

As per Azure [HDInsight documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-external-metadata-stores),

I see new user interface with existing Hive metastore database name input and not needed to authenticate the database connection.[image: Metastore configuration with no authentication]

Is this UI as per expectation and database credentials will be fetched by HDInsight deployment process in background?

Error for cluster creation - FailedToSetupDatabaseErrorCode

Detail Error-

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"FailedToSetupDatabaseErrorCode\",\r\n \"message\": \"Internal server error occurred while processing the request. Please retry the request or contact support.\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}
```

Comment: Could you please share complete error message from the activity log?
Note: If you share a metastore across multiple clusters, ensure all the clusters are the same HDInsight version. Different Hive versions use different metastore database schemas. For example, you can't share a metastore across Hive 2.1 and Hive 3.1 versioned clusters.

Comment: I added error details

Comment: Does the Hive Metastore connected to any other cluster? If yes, please share the cluster version and Hive version?

Comment: HDI 4.0, Spark 2.4 were the version

Comment: Could you please retry to create HDInsight cluster and check if the error persists?

Comment: Note:  it mandatory to configure the Authentication SQL Database.

Comment: yes I see in current screen, it is mandatory. For some reason, yesterday it was not appearing and I was able to submit cluster request without metastore databse credential. It is working now, Thanks for confirmation!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202040/discussion-between-cheekatlapradeep-msft-and-akshat-thakar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have configured "Authenticate SQL Database" to resolve this issue.

**Note:** It's mandatory to configure "**Authenticate SQL Database**" while creating Hive metastore with Azure HDInsight Cluster.

[image]

Hope this helps.